# Get std::chrono timestamp as string in %H.%M.%S format

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm working on a logging system for my console, and I'm trying to get a timestamp for when a entry was added to the log. I tried doing this;

```cpp
time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
char time_buffer[16] = { 0 };
std::strftime(time_buffer, sizeof(time_buffer), "%H.%M.%S", std::localtime(&now));
TextWrapped(time_buffer);
```

This almost works. The issue is that this works more as a clock then as a timestamp as it will not stay at the time of when the entry was logged, but increment... I think that I might have to use std::chrono::time_point, but I didn't really understand how to use it.

Comment: You have to store the result of std::chrono::system_clock::now() when logging and then put it into the code for output.

Comment: If you’re not against other libs. https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/time

Comment: What output are you getting, and how does that differ from the output you want?

Comment: I'm getting the correct output, but it acts as a clock and not as a timestamp. This means that it will not stay at e.g., 12.45.30, but will then start to increment to 12.45.31, ...32, ...33 and so on. This makes the timestamp for the logs useless as they will all have the same time and the time does not reflect when the logs got added.

Comment: Why can you not save the value of `now` and reuse it as often as you want, and then update it when you want?

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing now. This code snippet above, runs every time a new entry shall be logged.

Comment: Probably you should tell, how this code snippet is called. You expect several log messages (which belong together) to have the same timestamp? Can you describe more clearly, what you mean by 'time, the log got added' in comparison to time, the code snippet is called?

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 there are a number of nice functions in std::chrono to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>

int main()
{
    // get the current time
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // floor till the start of day
    auto start_of_day = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now);

    // round time till nearest seconds
    auto time_since_start_of_day = std::chrono::round<std::chrono::seconds>(now - start_of_day);

    // convert to hour minute second type
    std::chrono::hh_mm_ss hms { time_since_start_of_day };
    
    std::cout << time_since_start_of_day << "\n"; // will output number of seconds since start of day
    std::cout << hms << "\n"; // will output formatted time in hh:mm::ss

    auto string = std::format("{}", hms);
    std::cout << string << "\n"; // will output formatted time in hh:mm::ss

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you case a std::chrono::hh_mm_ss to a std::string or a c string?

Comment: Added, but I just noticed time is of by one hour on my system. Checking that.

Comment: probably a timezone issue?

Comment: Could be because I'm using Visual Studio 19 with "Preveiw Features" (need preview for those latest c++ features you used) that it is not working, but this code is spewing out errors. Like; "chrono(2738): error : no instance of function template "std::cend" "std::cbegin" "std::max" "std::size" matches the argument list" and more errors.

Comment: Could be true. Of all C++20 features, std::chrono still has lots of compiler incompatibilities.

Comment: I'm using : Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019,Version 16.11.5. C++ language set to  /std:c++latest

Comment: I'm using Mincrosfot Visual Studio 2019 with Intel C++ Compiler 19.2 with C++ language set to Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest).

Comment: Intel C++ does not have all new features of C++20. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp20 - to be fair 19.2 is not considered there, also cf. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/c20-features-supported-by-intel-cpp-compiler.html

Comment: Actually C++20 allows printing and formatting directly from `system_clock` without making it into a `time_duration`, however I don't have a compiler support that feature yet. But here's an example using the author of `<chrono>`'s `date` library: https://godbolt.org/z/EzcGP16bT

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.
The issue is that since my code snipped is in my render function, it will always update. My fix was to move the snippet above into my "add_log()" function, then write those timestamps into a new array, then in my for loop I would just grab from both arrays.
Kinda like so;

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < items.Size; i++) {
    TextWrapped(items[i]);
    TextWrapped(timestamps[i]);
}
```

It's a hacky solution, but it works.

Comment: If you want only one array, you have to create a struct type or `std::pair` with both as elements.